# Java canvas drawing socket

Tags: java, sockets, canvas

i have the following two functions

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    x=e.getX();
    y=e.getY();
    PrintStream ps;
    try {
        ps = new PrintStream(sc.getOutputStream());
        ps.println("!!##print"+" "+x+" "+" "+y+" "+x+" "+y);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    x1=e.getX();
    y1=e.getY();
    gr=canvas.getGraphics();
    gr.drawLine(x, y, x1, y1);
    if(x!=x1||y!=y1)
    {
        try {
        PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(sc.getOutputStream());
        ps.println("!!##print"+" "+x+" "+" "+y+" "+x1+" "+y1);
    } catch (IOException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    x=x1;
    y=y1;
}
```

The problem is when i use printstream to send the points it goes in a "server handler" where i print them in the console.I see that when i move fast with my mouse it can't get all points and the points will have spaces in them when i print them in other users canvas. How can i get all points where my mouse is going without lose them? What is not good at those functions?(sc is the socket to the server)
Here is the part where the paint command is handled in server(sock is an arraylist of sockets and sc is the current socket)

```
Iterator<Socket> it=sock.iterator();
                    while(it.hasNext())
                    {
                        Socket vv=it.next();
                        if(vv!=sc)
                        {
                            ps=new PrintStream (vv.getOutputStream());
                            ps.println(ms);
                        }   
                    }
```

Here is the part where the message is analyzed to see which points were transmited and to draw them.Here it all goes wrong because it doesn't get all messages which were transmitted by the server.Why this happens and how can i solve it?

```
else if(mes.charAt(0)=='!'&&mes.charAt(1)=='!'&&mes.charAt(2)=='#'&&mes.charAt(3)=='#'&&
                        mes.charAt(4)=='p'&&mes.charAt(5)=='r'&&mes.charAt(6)=='i'&&mes.charAt(7)=='n'&&
                        mes.charAt(8)=='t'
                        )
                {
                    StringTokenizer tok=new StringTokenizer(mes);
                    String aii=tok.nextToken();
                    ArrayList<Integer> numere=new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
                    {   
                        numere.add(Integer.parseInt(tok.nextToken()));
                    }
                    Graphics gs=canvas.getGraphics();
                    gs.drawLine(numere.get(0), numere.get(1), numere.get(2), numere.get(3));
                }
```

Comment: So i'm assuming `sc` is a socket connection to a server?

Comment: yes.sorry for not saying this

Comment: and the matter is that on my canvas it is a continuous line if i hold the mouse button down and drag but when i transmit the points in the console i see that there are points which are missing

Comment: are you sure there aren't just less points when the mouse moves faster?

Comment: but why on my canvas it "draw" a continuous line but if i transmit the points which i get and draw on other client canvas there is discontinuous line? why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue might be with your `PrintStream` resource. You open a new one every time a new pixel is drawn, and it might be so quickly that the previous one didn't have time to close so it just throws an `IOException`. I recommend that in your `main` function or somewhere where your server connection (`sc`) is made you declare a global `PrintStream` as well so that you don't have to keep opening and closing one. Example:

```
Socket sc;
PrintStream ps;

public static void main(String a[]){
    sc = new Socket("example.com");
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(sc.getOutputStream());
}
```

Once that is made simply access the global `PrintStream` to send data to your server. Hope this helps!

Comment: don't work.on my current canvas where i draw is everything ok but when i transmit all points to other users and draw on their canvas everything goes bad. i can't understand why

Comment: Try debugging your program and seeing if all of the points are actually successfully sent to the server. If they are, debug the other user program and check if they are receiving all of the points.

Comment: as i say in the comments above when i look at the points which are received i see that some point are missing(i mean, they are not continuous,they jump over a number of pixels as fast as i move the mouse) and my question is why it jumps and if it is correct to jump why on my canvas i see those points too?

Comment: Debug the program you are drawing with, and make sure that all the points are correctly sent to the server, and theres no `IOExceptions` or anything

Comment: i see that all data goes well to the server. the problem is when the server goes through all sockets and transmit that data i see that the others sockets doesn't get all data and this is why all happens.my question is why this happens?

Comment: Alright, so the server does transmit all of the data and the users only receive parts of it? Sounds like packet loss, are you using a spotty router or something? Can you show where your user programs recieve the packets as well? Also, that massive `if` statement can be replaced with `if(mes.startsWith("!!##print")`.

Comment: what solved this was to transmit not the points but a vector with 40 points and every user to paint them.this solved my problem.the server didn't get all  points and i don't know at this moment why but if i transfer it much points i think it has more time to analyse every message and transmit it.

Comment: @User124235 well, if it works it works! Good luck with the rest.

Comment: thx anyway for the adive to debug it.it took me from yesterday until 3 hours ago to see where it fails or not.if you will have any idea why it doesn't go well if i send every point say.